# Water damage around bathtub floor

Tags: plumbing-fixture

My bathtub is pulling from tile on one side and the floor tile is damage on the same side of the tube. How do I go about repairing this?

Comment: please send some photos of the damage

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll definitely need more info (e.g. pictures) before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.